# Function returning a dictionary with early binding in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to early bind Dictionaries in a Function? I would like to avoid that users have to explicit activate that reference to get the workbook working:

[image]

```
Function RngToDict (rng As Range) As Dictionary    
End Function
```

Comment: Yes there is, please google...

Comment: Thanks @kin Siang, i already did it but nothing works for me when try returning a Dictionay in a function

Comment: Read this https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/10855/early-binding-vs-late-binding

Comment: _Microsoft Scripting Runtime_ is the library which you are looking for. You just add it the reference to your file and this _mark_ will travel with it. As the _Microsoft Scripting Runtime_  is quite old and available and on every computer with Winows on it this should work for this group of computers. But be aware this approach will probably not work for other libraries because of version differeneces/conflicts.

Comment: As @Storax mentioned, use early binding and the users do not do anything. In no normal programming language a user is supposed to add a library by themselves. VBA is included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Early binding*** is a great solution, if you distribute the code to other users having the same system as you, because the checkmark "travels" with it and thus it relates to the corresponding library in the users' computers. The correct library for a dictionary is *Microsoft Scripting Runtime*.

Anyway, if you want to return a dictionary from a function with early binding for some "scientific" reasons, this is a way to do it:

- return an object from a function
- cast it to a dictionary in the function

---

```
Function myDict() As Object        
    Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    myDict.Add "Foo", "Bar"        
End Function    

Public Sub PrintDictionary(myDict As Object)        
    Dim key     As Variant
    For Each key In myDict.Keys
        Debug.Print key; "-->"; myDict(key)
    Next key        
End Sub

Sub TestMe()        
    PrintDictionary myDict    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Early binding is a great solution, if you distribute the code to other users, because it "travels" with its libraries and no user should take care of anything.` No that is not true. It doesn't "Travel" like you mentioned. Early binding is good for common libraries. Otherwise it is not a very good idea and can create `Reference` issues. For exactly this purpose, late binding should be used as you have done it. :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: That's what I tried to say in my comment to the original post but unfortunately not very clear. And IMHO early binding is possibly only good for _Microsoft Scripting Runtime_ because that library is/should be  available on every Windows Computer in the same "version" as it has not been changed for a long time. But one can already run into trouble with Microsoft Office libraries due to different versions. And, of course, I use early binding during developing.

Comment: @SiddharthRout - true. But for someone working in a corporate business, where noone has admin rights and everyone has the same version of anything, I am looking at it from my point of view :)

Comment: From whatever point you look at it, the libraries **never travel** when you disctribute your code or the excel file which has the code. Your statement is incorrect. If you would have said that the "CheckMark" travels like @Storax mentioned then that would have been ok :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout - yup.